# reading dynamic/java page using webrequest

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control, webrequest

I have a VB.NET (2010) forms project, and I want to read a webpage that has a java script on it, generating log output.

But when I do a request to the webpage, I only get the static part of the page.

When I fire the URL in a browser, it displays dynamic content and is updated regularry.

Whats the best wat to execute javascript remotely from vb.net.

Comment: I don't have a VB.NET port, but you could possibly find a C#-based solution here: stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303

Comment: @noseratio
problem with the webbrowser object is;
-hard to suppress the credentials dialog of windows security
-the ssl certificate is self signed, so users get a pop-up

Comment: It's hard but possible. Or you have another option: register your own root certificate on the target machine when you install your `WebBrowser`-based app.

Comment: So thats where the webbrowser path ends...

Comment: This *not* specific to `WebBrowser`. It's just the non-deterministic nature of the modern dynamic web pages. E.g, you'd have the same problem with PhantomJS.